# Validate string with parse

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to validate 3 values, one that is entered manually and the other two are selected with the picker, in the end it is not validated and an error appears, I need that when the user has not entered any value, an alert pops up saying that all fields must be completed, but I can't see how to implement it.

```
void CalculateBMI(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      
            double weight = Double.Parse(peso.Text);
            double feets = Double.Parse(Pies.SelectedItem.ToString());
            double inches = Double.Parse(Pulgadas.SelectedItem.ToString());

            double totalInches = (feets * 12) + inches;
            double bmi = (weight * 703) / (totalInches * totalInches);
            lblBMIValue.Text = String.Format("Your BMI is {0:0.00}", bmi);
            string bmiLevel = "";
            Color color = Color.Transparent;
            lblBMI.TextColor = Color.White;

            if ((weight <= 0) || (inches <= 0) || (feets <= 0))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please complete all the data.", "Ok");
                return;
            }
            else if (bmi < 18.5)
            {
                bmiLevel = "Underweight"; color = Color.FromHex("FECD57");
            }
            else if (bmi < 25)
            {
                bmiLevel = "Normal"; color = Color.FromHex("1287CE");
            }
            else if (bmi < 30)
            {
                bmiLevel = "Overweight"; color = Color.FromHex("FECD57");
            }
            else
            {
                bmiLevel = "Obese"; color = Color.FromHex("EC5564");
            }
            lblBMI.Text = bmiLevel;
            bmiStack.BackgroundColor = color;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user does not enter anything in the entry, the `Text` of entry is `Empty("")`;

If a user does not select anything in the picker, the `SelectedItem` of picker is null;

And in your `CalculateBMI` function, you should first validate 3 values and then calculate BMI:

```
void CalculateBMI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(peso.Text)) || (Pies.SelectedItem == null) || (Pulgadas.SelectedItem == null))
    {
        DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please complete all the data.", "Ok");
        return;
    }

    double weight = Double.Parse(peso.Text);
    double feets = Double.Parse(Pies.SelectedItem.ToString());
    double inches = Double.Parse(Pulgadas.SelectedItem.ToString());

    double totalInches = (feets * 12) + inches;
    double bmi = (weight * 703) / (totalInches * totalInches);
    lblBMIValue.Text = String.Format("Your BMI is {0:0.00}", bmi);
    string bmiLevel = "";
    Color color = Color.Transparent;
    lblBMI.TextColor = Color.White;

    if (bmi < 18.5)
    {
        bmiLevel = "Underweight"; color = Color.FromHex("FECD57");
    }
    else if (bmi < 25)
    {
        bmiLevel = "Normal"; color = Color.FromHex("1287CE");
    }
    else if (bmi < 30)
    {
        bmiLevel = "Overweight"; color = Color.FromHex("FECD57");
    }
    else
    {
        bmiLevel = "Obese"; color = Color.FromHex("EC5564");
    }
    lblBMI.Text = bmiLevel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool error = false;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(peso.Text) ||
    Pies.SelectedItem == null ||
    Pulgadas.SelectedItem == null)
{
   error = true;
   // display error message
}
```